# Integrating systems and snapshotting data exchange

Tags: integration

I wanted to know, if in general, when integrating 2 or more systems via whatever means (ie. webservice, MQ, etc.), is it a best practice or a standard for your system to capture a snapshot of data that you are sending with another system? I am thinking that this is as an insurance when reconciling is required for scenarios such as prod incidents.

Secondly, I would think this data snapshot is different from audit trail, in that the data being sent itself is saved (ie. xml data, csv file)  as a LOB column in a snapshot table. Is this redundant with the audit trail?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question ...

I've done many, many integrations using queues, web services, etc. and I will usually store an audit trail (a high level set of data telling me what happened), but I've never actually stored the payload itself for each call.

A few reasons for that:

1. The storage of the payloads being sent back and forth can get quite large.
2. I can usually reconstruct the payload using the audit trail. "Oh entity XYZ with ID 123 was sent yesterday. Let's take a look at what that entity looks like."
3. If you do the integration really well and have good testing around it, having copies of the payloads becomes unnecessary.

Instead of storing a copy of the payload I would focus on these things for integration:

1. Good unit tests on both sides *and* integration testing for the entire process.
2. Audit logs as you mentioned.
3. Good retry policies when a message fails (specifically for queues and topics).
4. Focusing on idempotent messages. So if something fails, you just do it again and everything is ok.